# Passing unix domain sockets as STDIN, then using them in child processes

Tags: c++, sockets, ipc, unix-socket

I am working on an archaically old code base. Within this code base, we create unix domain sockets, and we pass those to child processes as stdin:

```
int listenFD = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
...
if( dup2(listenFD, STDIN_FILENO) != 0 )
{
    warn("ChildProc", "Could not listen on socket fd %d, "
                 "dup2() failed: %d (%s)",
                 listenFD, errno, strerror(errno));
    return;
}
```

This appears to be working. I can vouch via logging from my main process that the socket opens. I can also confirm that the file path looks like a socket:

```
/logs% ll  /var/my.sock
srw------- 1 nobody nobody 0 Jun 21 10:30 /var/my.sock
```

However, I can't seem to utilize the socket in the child process. I get error messages akin to this:

> The FastCGI domain socket is not open.  Ensure the parent of this process has opened the domain socket.

It looks to me like I have opened the domain socket. Is there something I'm missing or overlooking?

Comment: Have you listened and accepted a connection on that socket? Stuffing the listening socket into `stdin` isn't going to accomplish anything useful. A connection needs to be accepted, and that's what goes into stdin and/or stdout.

Comment: I ... can't seem to find any code that does that in the existing code base (parent process) that I am porting in. If that were expected to happen in one of the children, is that even feasible? If I 'stuff the listen socket into stdin' and then a child attempts to listen on it's stdin, does that even remotely pass smell test?

Comment: Well, certainly, if the child process listens and accepts a connection on its file descriptor 0 -- that can be done. But it's unclear what your question would be about, then. Try to perform the following thought experiement: forget everything you know about the existing application and code base. Read only what's written above, which includes the comments. Can you explain what the question is asking, then, that complete strangers, that don't know anything about your code base, might be able to answer?

Comment: Either the child process expects a file descriptor on standard input that's an actual connection, that can now be read or written to, or a listening socket, that connections get accepted on. Those are the only possibilities.